# How to detect when a user taps on a view in Android

Tags: android

I want to detect when a user taps anywhere in a view in my Android application.

My code looks like this:

```
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout); // main layout
// ...
linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
// ...
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Touch!", 1000);
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Down!", 1000);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

...but when I click on the view, I don't get Toast!

Do touch events work in the emulator -- or have I got something wrong in my code?

Comment: I was looking for same solutions. Thanks Biswajit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the problem is with your message-displaying code rather than your touch-detecting code.

You're creating the `Toast` object but you're not displaying it.  You need to call the [`show()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#show()).

Also, the `duration` argument to [the `makeText()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)) should be one of [`LENGTH_SHORT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_SHORT) or [`LENGTH_LONG`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_LONG).

Try:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Down!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: We've all been there...well I have anyway...twice.